# vectorially calculating the product of specific columns

Tags: r, vectorization

I have a matrix with 2 types of column names: those ending with "min" and those ending with "max".
for example, the first row and first 6 columns of this matrix can be:

```
M = matrix(c(0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.9, 0.7, 0.6), nrow = 1, ncol = 6)
colnames(M) = c("a_min", "b_min", "c_min", "a_max", "b_max", "c_max")
```

I would like, for each row of `M`, to calculate the product of the difference between `a_max` and `a_min`, `b_max` and `b_min`, and so on for all pairs of columns.

In the example above, the final product is:

```
(0.9-0.2)*(0.7-0.3)*(0.6-0.5) = 0.028.
```

How can I do it vectorially for a general `2N` columns and `P` rows?

Comment: If you had more than one row, how would the calculation work?

Comment: for each row I would have one number as the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate `max - min` differences, just subtract matrices, e.g.

```
D <- M[, grep('_max', colnames(M))] - M[, grep('_min', colnames(M))]
```

(you must check that the columns are ordered correctly or the wrong differences will be calculated).

This will give you a matrix of differences, and now you want to calculate row products. You can do this e.g. with a loop or `apply` but it's much faster to use `rowProds` from the `matrixstats` package

```
matrixStats::rowProds(D)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea via base R,

```
Reduce(`*`, lapply(split.default(M, sub('_.*', '', colnames(M))), diff))
#[1] 0.028
```

If you have multiple rows then, i.e. `M <- rbind(M, M)`

```
Reduce(`*`, lapply(split.default(as.data.frame(M), sub('_.*', '', colnames(M))), 
                                                             function(i) abs(i[1] - i[2])))
#  a_min
#1 0.028
#2 0.028
```

Comment: awesome one liner! probably wouldn't have thought of this